# How to mouseover linestring to create marker in Openlayer?

Tags: openlayers

If you create a linestring in openlayers, how do you make it such that when you hover along the segment of a linestring, a marker pops up where the user hovers over?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/highlight-feature.html

The most important is:
hover : true

For popups look here:
http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/select-feature-openpopup.html

Comment: The issue is assuming there are multiple points on the linestring, I want the hover event to popup related to, for example, just that particular point on the linestring as opposed to the linestring as a whole. In the example you provide the hover event applies to the entire polygon and not just the point within the polygon.